# jquery: Alert val

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

This is a quick one...

Why doesn't it work?

```
var currentSlideshow = $(".slideshow div").index();     
$('#menu ul li a').click(function() {
    alert("currentSlideshow");


});
```

It won't alert anything.

Comment: Posibly your click event is not triggering because the selector is wrong?

Comment: Do you mean it does not alert at all or it does not alert the index you saved. If #2 then Shota answered

Comment: Does your `ul` or its *container* have the `id` of '#menu'?

Comment: It could be that there are no listeners because your selector is off. verify that the selector returns items.

Comment: Better error description => better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are alerting a string "currentSlideshow" instead of a variable  currentSlideshow

Comment: So? Then it would still alert the string. It states that it don't alert at all

Comment: Then it's a problem with your selector.

Comment: @TurBas: for me the phrase *[it] won't alert anything* implies that nothing is alerted, not that there is no alert. ...though I'm a strange English Lit grad, so...I'm maybe just a bit odd with language.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not selecting anything.

```
#menu ul li a
```

1. Do you have something with **id** of menu?
2. Do you have a `<ul>` as a child the element with id of menu?
3. Are there `<li>` elements within the `<ul>`?
4. Do the `<li>` elements have `<a>` elements?

Answer (score 1):

I rebuild your example: [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z53eX/) there the event fires.

EDIT: pasted the code from jsfiddle

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>

    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="slideshow" id="4"><div id="5"></div></div>
```

JS

```
var currentSlideshow = $(".slideshow div").index();     
$('#menu ul li a').click(function() {
   alert("currentSlideshow");
});
```

Comment: great effort, would be nice if you would copy the code over to here so we don't have to click to see it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that selector never matches an element so the click event is never fired.

Can you post the HTML so we can see if there is a problem there?

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested please check that the selector is correct. This can be done using firebug, for example.. Try this, add a breakpoint in the handler function, check if it breaks on it.. also, if it is only for the purpose of debugging, use firebug console.